# How to find a number divisible by 7 in Visual Basic using function?

Tags: vb.net

My task is: Display numbers that are divisible by 7 (range 10-25). Calculate and display an average of the numbers that are not divisible by 7

So I wrote this code in Visual Basic. How can it be improved? I do not know how to display numbers 14 and 21 in other way.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim counter As Byte = 0
    Dim accumulator As Short = 0
    Dim average As Single
    Dim loopcounter As Byte

    For loopcounter = 10 To 25
        If loopcounter Mod 7 <> 0 Then
            accumulator += loopcounter
            counter += 1
        Else
            Label1.Text = loopcounter & ", 14"
        End If
    Next

    average = accumulator / counter
    Label2.Text = average
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the numbers divisible by 7 into a `List(Of Integer)` and then use [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) to combine them into a string at the end of the loop.

```
    Dim counter As Byte = 0
    Dim accumulator As Short = 0
    Dim average As Single
    Dim loopcounter As Byte
    Dim multiples As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()  ' Declare list

    For loopcounter = 10 To 25
        If loopcounter Mod 7 <> 0 Then
            accumulator += loopcounter
            counter += 1
        Else
            multiples.Add(loopcounter)  ' Add multiple of 7 to list
        End If
    Next

    Label1.Text = String.Join(", ", multiples) ' Combine list into a comma-separated string
    average = accumulator / counter
    Label2.Text = average
```